# Calling jQuery function from multiple MVC @Html controls

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I need to call a single javascript function from different @Html controls in a view. Below is the view

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.val1,new { @Value = Model.val1.ToString("dd-MMM-yyyy"), @onfocus = "func1()" })
<div class="class1">
    <p class="class2">
        <label>
            @(Html.Label<labelmodel>(x => x.val2))
        </label>
        <div class="class3">
            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.val3, new SelectList(ViewBag.Names, "Code", "Code"),
            new { @onchange = "func1()", id = "_val3Id" })</div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.val4, new { @onchange = "func1()", id = "_val4Id" })
    </p>
</div>
```

And i tried calling using

```
$(function func1(){...});
```

Unluckly it didnt work, so I had to choose

```
window.func1= function () {...};
```

which I'm sure not the proper way. And this function is getting triggered multiple times.

Any other workaround?

Comment: try giving the control a class and use that class to call the function. e.g. assuming your textboxes have the class 'myTextBox' then in your jquery you can write $('.myTextbox').on('change', function(){});

Comment: Pls post the generated HTML as server side code wouln't help us to help you!